# How to copy contents of one text file to another with reduced length?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I have a text file with about 5,000 lines and I want to copy its contents to another file, but only the first 38 characters of each line.

I currently have this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string line, line2;

        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            line2 = line.Substring(0, 38);
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter files = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\test2.txt"))
            {
                files.WriteLine(line2);
            }
        }

        file.Close();
    }
```

It only copies the last line. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you rewrite your new file in your loop. You should create your new string in the loop (use a stringBuilder for this will be more efficient), but write the new file out of the loop :

```
    string line;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt");
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        sb.AppendLine(line.Substring(0, Math.Min(38, line.Length)));

    file.Close();
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter files = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\test2.txt"))
        {
            files.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
```

or to do it shorter

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\test.txt")
                 .Select(m => m.Substring(0, Math.Min(38, m.Length)));
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\test2.txt", result);
```

Comment: Note that this copies it to memory first (to sb), which can be a problem if you have a very big file.

Comment: @JouniAro OP said 5000 lines... So yes in theory, but I would use second version anyway : see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3925077/961526

Comment: Yes, I know. I just found his original approach working fine, despite the using line being misplaced, so did not really see a need to refactor it any more.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the creation of 'file2' before the while loop. 
You should also create 'file' in a using:. You won't need to call close for either one then.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string line;

    using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt"))
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file2 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\test2.txt"))
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string line2 = line.Substring(0, 38);
                file2.WriteLine(line2);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file's `.WriteLine` overwrites the entire file every time you call it. Therefore, put the entire code in your `using` block, or add `true` to the `StreamWriter`'s arguments to tell it to append to the file instead of overwriting.

Option 1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string line, line2;
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter files = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\test2.txt"))
        {
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            line2 = line.Substring(0, 38);

            files.WriteLine(line2);

        }

        file.Close();
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string line, line2;

        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            line2 = line.Substring(0, 38);
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter files = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\test2.txt",true))
            {
                files.WriteLine(line2);
            }
        }

        file.Close();
    }
```

And finally, if you choose to use a StringBuilder, you can use `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test2.txt", stringHere);` instead of the entire `using` and `StreamWriter` block

Comment: Why would you have a using statement for the streamWriter but not for the streamReader?

Comment: You should probably use "using" for both, but I copied to the Q's code and edited it minimally to solve his problem.