# Using the "using" statement with StreamWriter/Reader inside loop

Tags: c#, using, streamreader, streamwriter

Here is my situation.

1. Read one line from a text file
2. "Process" the line
3. Write the "processed" line to a new text file
4. Loop to #1 and repeat until EOF

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
using (StreamReader srReader = new StreamReader(strInputFile))
{
    // loop until EOF
    while ((strCurrentLine = srReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // "process" strCurrentLine...

        // write the "processed" strCurrentLine to a new text file
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFullOutputPathFileName, false))
        {
            // write strCurrentLine to the new file
            sw.WriteLine("stuff...");
        }
     }
}
```

My manager tells me that using the `using` statement like I am inside of a loop will extremely hinder performance. The reason is because the `StreamWriter` instance will be created as many times as I'm looping. So, if I looped 1,000 times, I'd have 1,000 instances of my `StreamWriter` object, which could severely hinder performance.

Is this true? Also, is my method above the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Surely the bigger problem than performance is the fact that you're *not* appending - so your final file will just be the last line of the input file...

Comment: `I'd have 1,000 instances` Well, no. But you'd have *created* one 1000 times.

Comment: The using statement isn't a performance problem, but calling "new StreamWriter" 1000 times instead of once is. As the other comments point out, though, the fact that you are overwriting your file 999 times is a bigger issue.

Comment: See [C# I/O - Difference between System.IO.File and StreamWriter/StreamReader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924469/c-sharp-i-o-difference-between-system-io-file-and-streamwriter-streamreader). I prefer using `File.ReadAllText()` and `File.WriteAllText()` over `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah, i am appending...i copied the wrong line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My manager tells me that using the using statement like I am inside of a loop will extremely hinder performance. The reason is because the StreamWriter instance will be created as many times as I'm looping. So, if I looped 1,000 times, I'd have 1,000 instances of my StreamWriter object, which could severely hinder performance.
>
> Is this true?

Well, it's true, but not because you're creating *instances*, but because you're opening and closing a file 1,000 times.  You could create 1,000 strings with almost no impact to performance.

> Also, is my method above the best way to accomplish this?

To start, move the writer creation outside of the `while` loop:

```
using (StreamReader srReader = new StreamReader(strInputFile))
{
    // write the "processed" strCurrentLine to a new text file
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFullOutputPathFileName, false))
    {
        // loop until EOF
        while ((strCurrentLine = srReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // "process" strCurrentLine...

            // write strCurrentLine to the new file
            sw.WriteLine("stuff...");
        }
     }
}
```

However, you could also read the entire file into memory, process it, and write it out in one operation.  The impact will depend on the processing that's done and whether you want partial results if there's an error.

Answer (score 4):

Change your code to:

```
using (StreamReader srReader = new StreamReader(strInputFile))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFullOutputPathFileName, false))
    {
        while ((strCurrentLine = srReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("stuff...");
        }
    }
}
```

And also, check Jon's comment about appending.

Comment: It's convention to drop the outer `{}` and place the usings statements on the same indent level.

Comment: I've seen it in use but I didn't know it was convention. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

If your file isn't big you can use File.ReadAllLines to get file lines in a string array and do your processing afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be creating many StreamWriters by doing it that way (not many instances running simultaneously, however). A simple way to solve this is by creating the StreamWriter before you even enter the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should open and close the file as few times as possible.
So open it (create streamwriter) before the while loop.
In the loop use sw.WriteLine("stuff...")
After the loop call sw.Close().

Your manager is wrong in sense that it won't create 1000 instances because each instance will be released at the end of the iteration, but you'll be opening and closing the file which will impact the performance.

Regards,
Damjan

Comment: No, it *will* create 1000 instances. They won't all be "live" at the same time, but it will definitely create 1000 instances...

Comment: Also the claim that _each instance will be released at the en of the iteration_ is imprecise; they _may_ be released then, but there is no guarantee as to when the garbage collector will process them. It will probably happan relatively soon, but unless I'm mistaken, the instances could in theory continue to exist in memory for a while even after they are out of scope.

Comment: I agree with both of you Jon and Kjartan.