# Difference File and Streamwriter class

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

What is the difference between using File from using `System.IO` & `StreamWriter` from using `System.IO`?

I am using `File.WriteAllLines` but in many internet-source-codes they are using:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("important.txt"))
{
   writer.Write("Word ");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# I/O - Difference between System.IO.File and StreamWriter/StreamReader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924469/c-sharp-i-o-difference-between-system-io-file-and-streamwriter-streamreader)

Answer (score 4):

`File.WriteAllLines` is simply a convenience method that internally uses a `StreamWriter`, which in turn uses a `FileStream` to write to the file.

The main difference is that while `File.WriteAllLines` only writes to files, a `StreamWriter` can write to any stream, for example a network stream.

Either way works, use what suits you the best.