# How to add the value of each dictionary in a new line in txt?

Tags: c#, file, dictionary, .net-3.5

I am consulting an information and I am saving it in a dictionary (I have about 1000 dictionaries) and I want the values of each dictionary to be stored in a line,

but my code currently overwrites each time a new dictionary is read. How can I make it Does each line have the values of each dictionary?

```
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dictionary = objeto.diccionary;
        string valueDic = "";


        string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"myfile.txt");


        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Create(path).Dispose();

            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path))
            {
                foreach (var entry in dictionary)
                {

                    valueDic = valueDic + "|" + entry.Value.ToString();

                }
                file.WriteLine(valueDic);
            }

        }
        else if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("myfile.txt"))
            {
                foreach (var entry in dictionary)
                {
            //        //file.WriteLine("[{0} {1}]", entry.Key, entry.Value);
                    valueDic = valueDic + "|" + entry.Value.ToString();

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you need to save it like this in a text document, assuming you will want to read it at some point, you don't want to use a better way of saving the data? Did you check into `File.AppendText(path)` to create a streamwriter, or maybe `File.AppendAllLines( path, IEnumerable<string>)`

Comment: @Icepickle but I work in framework 3.5

Comment: That's good information to add to your question :)

Comment: @AlexZ just for future reference, there's a .net-3.5 flag you can add to your question to specify which version you're using. Its helpful for us to know so that we can  make sure our answers work with your configuration - otherwise we tend to assume you're using the latest main version.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare your new StreamWriter with the flag append set to true, it will add to the file instead of overwriting:

```
new StreamWriter(path, append: true)
```

You'd want to change your else if to this:

```
else if (File.Exists(path))
{
    using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("myfile.txt", append: true))
    {
        foreach (var entry in dictionary)
        {
            //        //file.WriteLine("[{0} {1}]", entry.Key, entry.Value);
            valueDic = valueDic + "|" + entry.Value.ToString();

        }
        file.WriteLine(valueDic);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

If you're using .Net 3.5 and can't use optional parameters, just replace append: true with true:

```
new StreamWriter(path, true)
```

Also, when you declare a new StreamWriter in append mode, the file doesn't need to already exist - it will automatically create it if it doesn't exist. All you'd need is to replace your if/else statement with just this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary = objeto.diccionary;
string valueDic = "";

string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"myfile.txt");

using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("myfile.txt", append: true))
{
    foreach (var entry in dictionary)
    {
        valueDic = valueDic + "|" + entry.Value.ToString();
    }
    file.WriteLine(valueDic);
}
```

But, like Icepickle's answer says, there are more elegant and reusable ways to deal with this entire scenario.

Comment: Good and concise, but would the file need to exist before you can use `append: true`?

Comment: Fair point - the file would not need to exist. I'll add a note about that - I figured there might be some reason he was using two different sets of logic, but it doesn't appear to be so from the example code.

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with your code as it is, you really don't need to create the file as you do when it doesn't exist, there are some easier ways to go about this.

For one, you really don't have to create a file manually, this is usually handled by the methods provided to you by the framework, or by specifying a `FileMode` like `OpenOrCreate` or `Create` or `Append`.

Another thing to note is that you do the same operation twice, once when you are creating the file, once when you are trying to append to the file. This is a bit error prone, if you would change the formatting at a later time, you could forget about the two methods, and then create or append create different strings.

I wrote a bit of a sample which other ways you could go at it.

For example, you could consider this option, of creating the filestream itself, using `FileMode.Append`

```
static void WriteDictionaryToFile<TKey, TValue>( IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, string filename )
{
  using (var fs = new StreamWriter( new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write ) ) )
  {
    foreach (var kvp in dict)
    {
      fs.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}|{1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
    }
  } 
}
```

However, there is no real need to go that deep to create a `StreamWriter` for appending text to it, C# 3.5 already provides you with the following option, using `File.AppendText` instead

```
static void WriteDictionaryToFileEasy<TKey, TValue>( IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, string filename)
{
  using (var fs = File.AppendText( filename ))
  {
    foreach (var kvp in dict)
    {
      fs.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}|{1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
    }
  }
}
```

Or if you feel secure enough to use Linq, you could use the `File.AppendAllText` method instead, although that might feel a bit akward, as we have to add the final newline only when the dictionary is not empty (this is in absence of the `File.AppendAllLines` method, that would take care of that for you )

```
static void WriteDictionaryToFileLinq<TKey, TValue>( IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, string filename)
{
  if ( dict == null || dict.Count == 0)
  {
    return;
  }
  File.AppendAllText(
    filename, 
    string.Join(
      Environment.NewLine, 
      dict.Select( kvp => string.Format("{0}|{1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value) )
        .Concat( new[] { string.Empty } ).ToArray() 
    )  
  );
}
```

(I added the line breaks purely for readability here)

If you throw that all together, you could use the program like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
  {
    { "key1", "value1" }
  };

  string targetFile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "temp.txt");
  if (File.Exists( targetFile))
  {
    File.Delete(targetFile);
  }
  WriteDictionaryToFile(dict, targetFile);
  WriteDictionaryToFileEasy(dict, targetFile);
  WriteDictionaryToFileLinq(dict, targetFile);

  var lines = File.ReadAllLines(targetFile);
  Debug.Assert(lines.Length == 3, "Expected exactly 3 lines");
  Debug.Assert(string.Equals(lines[0], "key1|value1"), "First line should equal 'key1|value1'");
}
```

A final point of consideration is what you want to do with the eventual data that you have stored. I guess at a certain time, you will want to retrieve the data from the files into some dictionaries.

This could potentially create some errors, like having keys or values containing the `|` character, or most likely, having saved multiple same named keys, just be aware of that, as the question didn't deal with how you would store this data, I am leaving that part open with a warning

Comment: Good alternative. Definitely more elegant overall than using regular StreamWriters. Always find the answer here interesting, referring to the usability of File wrapper methods vs a regular StreamWriter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924469/c-sharp-i-o-difference-between-system-io-file-and-streamwriter-streamreader